# My windows 10 copy/paste clipboard is blocked, what could be the cause?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

So I just noticed I cannot copy or paste anything. This also affects the clipboard history feature hidden under <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

What is the strangest thing is I found a tip on the internet that you can use windows `clip` command which accepts output from previous command and saves it into clipboard. So this should place "hello" in your clipboard:

```
echo hello | clip
```

Wish I knew about this in the past.

The weird part is I get an error even when trying with a super user shell:

```
D:\>echo dd | clip
ERROR: Access is denied
```

Glad the error is this short as I did have to manually rewrite it here.

Any ideas what could be happening? I can just restart my PC and per previous experiences, it should fix it, but I'd love to know what is going on.

Additional context:

- PC is fully updated as per IT policy - this is a work machine
- Restarting the clipboard service alone did not fix the issue
- restarting the PC fixes the problem every time it has occurred, but this can be inconvenient at times

Comment: Is the `Clipboard User Service` running?

Comment: Yes. I restarted it now and it has not solved the problem.

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: See https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-windows-clipboard-not-working-windows-10/

Comment: have you tried running windows updates to the latest?

Comment: As I said, restart fixes this in my experience - and that has worked now as well. That fixed normal usage, the clip command and the windows clipboard history feature. This is why my question was more aimed on what is happening. I never heard anyone else complain about this, and it happens fairly often to me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but sharing this since it started to happen to me. What I found was that an application had managed to get exclusive control of the Windows clipboard preventing any copying/pasting. Running clip from the command line returned the same "ERROR: Access is denied" response.

Simply closing the application/ending the process restored clipboard functionality.

The offending app was a third party note taking application that I use very often, seems to be a bug that occurs when hitting copy with no content. Probably due to some poor logic when interacting with the Windows clipboard API.

Comment: How did you discover which application is responsible? It happened to me once more since asking and I'd like to know so that next time I don't have to restart my computer.

Comment: Unfortunately it was trial and error, not sure if there is an easy way to identify which process is locking it. The second time it happened I just closed each application then ran Clip to see if access was restored to figure out which one was behind it.

Answer (score 0):

@Tomáš: I had to dig into this a bit myself as I was banging my head against this same wall. I don't think there's an easy way to determine the clipboard owner from i.e. Task Manager or Process Explorer, that I could find - but there is a Win32 API call for it. I ended up putting together a little utility for the job, which you can download at http://www.commodorejohn.com/whodunnit.zip - the code is very simple:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("Clipboard owner PID: %u\n",GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetClipboardOwner(),NULL));
}
```

It's still a little tricky - the PID returned can be for a specific thread, which you can't **taskkill** by and which won't show in Task Manager's "Details" view; but you can add PID as a column in the "Processes" view, which does show child threads. In my case, it turned out to be a particular Chrome thread locking the clipboard, and killing/relaunching it resolved the issue.